# unicode in irfanview

Tags: unicode, irfanview

I tried opening a picture and it mentions activating unicode.

```
UNICODE PlugIn in Properties->Languages
```

I only see english and german. I already installed the plugin pack (via exe). I still cant open unicode, how do i set it up?

Comment: *> I still cant open unicode*   “Open Unicode”? Do you mean you cannot open a file that has Unicode characters in its name? Have you selected the check-box at the bottom of the *Languages* options page you mentioned?

Comment: Just update to **version 4.50** or newer, which supports Unicode without need of plug-ins. See robotik's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from version 4.50 (released 2017-10-10) IrfanView supports Unicode natively, no more plugin or settings change required. Works both in the 32-bit and the [64-bit](https://www.irfanview.com/64bit.htm) version.

Answer (score 2):

As Synetech said, tick the `Load Unicode Plugin at program start (for filenames with non-latin characters)` checkbox.

[image]

Comment: When I open the window the option is disabled (http://i.stack.imgur.com/DSrb6.png) what am I doing wrong? It's really frustrating, I have loads of paths with Japanese names. I don't understand why such an essential feature isn't just enabled by default.

Comment: Okay it seems the unicode plugin (and a lot of other plugins apparently) isn't supported on the 64-bit version of the program, so you'll need the 32-bit version.

Comment: @asdasd: Is this still true (08.05.2016, 13.15)? I still can't activate this option in the newest 64bit version of Irfanview.

Comment: It only works in the 32-bit version.

Comment: Are there sources available to submit a patch somewhere for the 64bit version?

Comment: alternatives http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/12/windows/free-irfanview-alternative-software.html

Comment: @aliopi starting version 4.50 no plugin needed, works natively both in 32-bit and 64-bit.